# Trying to create a method in Ruby to return all possible combinations of an array using recursion (not built in methods like combination/permutation)

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm learning Ruby and would like to create a method that returns all possible combinations of an array using recursion without using built in methods like combination or permutation.
Specifically I would like to convert the following Javascript code into something similar for Ruby:

```
const combinations = (elements) => {
  if (elements.length === 0) return [ [] ];
  const firstEl = elements[0]
  const rest = elements.slice(1);

  const combsWithoutFirst = combinations(rest);
  const combsWithFirst = [];

  combsWithoutFirst.forEach(comb => {
    const combWithFirst = [...comb, firstEl];
    combsWithFirst.push(combWithFirst);
  });

  return [ ...combsWithoutFirst, ...combsWithFirst ];
}
```

I'm quite new to programming and I'm still trying to get my head around recursion, any help would be appreciated!

The code above comes from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NA2Oj9xqaZQ

Comment: SO is not a language transpilation service. You are expected to provide the code that you've tried, the minimum necessary data and code to reproduce your issue, any errors or stack traces produced, and a sample of what your expected output should be so that your examples are testable.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages along with "[How should we tag code translation questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/128421)". You need to use your best effort to solve the problem, then when you've exhausted your options, ask a specific question about a particular problem. Anything prior to that is premature.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on asking questions. I'll make sure to include my own code in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as follows.

```
def recurse(first, *rest)
  return [[first], rest] if rest.empty?
  recurse(*rest).flat_map { |a| [a, [first] + a] }
end
```

```
​arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

```
a = recurse(*arr)
  #=> [[5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [1, 2, 5], [3, 5], [1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5],
  #    [1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], [1], [2], [1, 2],
  #    [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4],
  #    [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

```
a.sort
  #=> [[],
  #    [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  #    [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3],
  #    [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4], [1, 4, 5], [1, 5],
  #    [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5],
  #    [3], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [3, 5],
  #    [4], [4, 5],
  #    [5]]
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

---

---

The best way to understand recursion is to add some puts statements to the code and to visually separate each instance of the method. That could be done here as follows.

```
INDENT = 6
def indent; $col += INDENT; end
def undent; $col -= INDENT; end
def pu(s); puts "#{" "*$col}#{s}"; end 
def puhline; pu('-'*(65-$col)); end
```

```
def recurse(first, *rest)
  indent
  puhline    
  pu "recurse called with arguments first = #{first}, rest = #{rest}"
  if rest.empty?
    c =  [[first], rest]
    pu "returning #{c}"
    puhline    
    undent
    return c
  end  
  pu "calling recurse(#{rest})"
  a = recurse(*rest)
  pu "#{a} is returned"
  b = a.flat_map { |a| [a, [first] + a] }
  pu "returning a.flat_map { |a| [a, [#{first}] + a] } = #{b}"
  puhline    
  undent
  b
end
```

```
$col = -INDENT
recurse(1,2,3,4)
```

The following is displayed. Note that calculations performed by each instance of the method are vertically aligned below.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
recurse called with arguments first = 1, rest = [2, 3, 4]
calling recurse([2, 3, 4])
      -----------------------------------------------------------
      recurse called with arguments first = 2, rest = [3, 4]
      calling recurse([3, 4])
            -----------------------------------------------------
            recurse called with arguments first = 3, rest = [4]
            calling recurse([4])
                  -----------------------------------------------
                  recurse called with arguments first = 4, rest = []
                  returning [[4], []]
                  -----------------------------------------------
            a = [[4], []] is returned
            returning a.flat_map { |a| [a, [3] + a] } = [[4], [3, 4], [], [3]]
            -----------------------------------------------------
      a = [[4], [3, 4], [], [3]] is returned
      returning a.flat_map { |a| [a, [2] + a] } = [[4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [], [2], [3], [2, 3]]
      -----------------------------------------------------------
a = [[4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [], [2], [3], [2, 3]] is returned
returning a.flat_map { |a| [a, [1] + a] } = [[4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```